# How can I highlight a div while on click using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a bunch of divs with class `tl-box`

[image]

I want to highlight the one I clicked on.

**Note:** 
if I click on a new div, **only** that new div should be highlighted.

---

### I've tried :

**jQuery**

```
$('.tl-box').click(function () {
  $(this).find('.tl-selected').removeClass('tl-selected');
  $(this).toggleClass('tl-selected');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.tl-selected{
    background: white;
    border:3px solid orange;
    width:179px;
    height:80px;
    position: relative;
}
```

**Result**

[image]

What is the best way to achieve something like this ?

[`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/va5qkycp/18/)

Answer (score 1):

you wont find the selected box inside another box, yet you are searching it within `$(this)`...

simply search for it this way:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.tl-box').click(function() {
    $('.tl-selected').removeClass('tl-selected');
    $(this).addClass('tl-selected');
  });
});
```

```css
.tl-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.tl-selected {
  background: white;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tl-box"></div>
<div class="tl-box"></div>
<div class="tl-box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$('.tl-box').click(function () {
  $(this).find('.tl-selected').removeClass('tl-selected');
  $(this).toggleClass('tl-selected');
});
```

to

```
$('.tl-box').click(function () {
  $('.tl-selected').removeClass('tl-selected');
  $(this).toggleClass('tl-selected');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first code snippet, `this` refers to the clicked item; so you won't find the previously highlighted item by searching inside it. Try replacing this:

```
$(this).find('.tl-selected').removeClass('tl-selected');
```

with this:

```
$('.tl-selected').removeClass('tl-selected');
```